# FireFox 4 and <%=Html.AntiForgeryToken()%> trouble

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox4

When I'm trying to login with FireFox4 , I've got error message (no errors with other browsers) :

Checking the state of the form MAC failed. If the application is a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration  points to the same verification key validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate can not be used in a cluster.

```
[ViewStateException: 
    Client IP: ::1
    Port: 
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
    ViewState: X+K7IAAB3XrqQMf0Ym7ZlHeMzvcISEek8a8NX07/uIQ1jEdwJp+/fisjPu64BgVKohucBKZxiX6vdxG+GNAS4qGMJbyCAfB6hwEKvpR9Df9o9gBj5MJTF2AHA6YO87XVvqbC3TNlTBSQ1OLakVvy7Q==
    Referer: http://localhost:1062/
    Path: /login]
```

login page is simple :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="ModelViewPage<Graphite.Web.Controllers.Login.LoginViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Graphite.Web.Controllers.Login" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="main" runat="server" >
<%
  using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate","Login")) {%>
  <div class="formInput"> 
       <%= this.TextBox(x => x.Username).Label("Username: ")%>
  </div>
  <div class="formInput">
      <%= this.Password(x => x.Password).Label("Password: ")%>
  </div>
  <%=Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
  <%=this.SubmitButton("Login")%>
<%
  }%>
</asp:Content>
```

I was trying to disable angry additions like no-script but it doesn't helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what is the URL to which the page is posting on login button (you can use firebug for that). My suspicion is that it is posting back to aspx page - instead of posting to url that will get routed to correct controller.

On different note, I will suggest you to disable the view-state in ASP.NET pages in MVC because you are using them only for rendering the output and not really using its control & post-back model.